# Changing Wireless Card Port

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop

I have a dumb question here, can I change the wireless port to another port (please see the picture). Will it work?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The port with the arrow going into it is an mSATA port for your SSD hard drive. The wifi card will be using mini-PCI or mini PCI-E so is a completely different interface. You cannot and must not put the wireless adapter into the port on the right.

To add: "An mSATA SSD is similar in size and appearance to a mini PCIe card, and both fit into the same mPCIe slot on the motherboard of a space-constrained computing device. However, an mSATA SSD uses the SATA storage bus interface and must have a direct connection to the SATA host controller." taken from https://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/mSATA-SSD-mSATA-solid-state-drive

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought that I could, the size seems the same :P